# How to get first day of particular week(week 2 in november) and last day of particular week(week 4 in november) using javascript

Tags: javascript, date, week-number, weekday

I need to implement a functionality in javascript which takes from week and to week  as inputs i.e it takes week number  of current month (ex : 1,2,3,4,5,6) and get the start date of the week and end day of other week in **current month** and **current year**

Ex: selecting **3** and **4** should give current month **3rd week** first day and **4th week** last day
In Nov:2018 output should be as 11/11/2018 and 24/11/2018

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please take a [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) of the [help centre](http://stackoverflow.com/help) to see [how to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and what types of question are [on topic](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) for the site.  We cannot help you if you do not provide any code - see how to create a [MCVE]

Comment: How do you work out the week in the month? Different cultures use a different first day of the week.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try below approach to figure out your expected result. Solution below takes month as an input so that we can verify for any month

```js
function getDates(m, a, b) {
  var date = new Date()
  , y = date.getFullYear()
  , lastDate = new Date(y, m, 0).getDate()
  
  var offset = new Date(new Date().setDate(1)).getDay()
  
  return [(a - 1) * 7 + 1, b * 7].map(d => {
    d -= offset
    if(d < 1) d = 1
    if(d > lastDate) d = lastDate
    return d + '/' + m + '/' + y
  })
}

console.log(getDates(11,1,2))
console.log(getDates(11,2,3))
console.log(getDates(11,3,4))
console.log(getDates(11,1,5))
```

Comment: `toLocaleDateString()` probably shouldn't be used. In my locale, `getDates(3, 4)` returned `["11/21/2018", "24/21/2018"]`, one of which isn't an actual date. But changing it to `toLocaleDateString('en-IN')` the answer comes out correct.

Comment: I realised adding 'en-In' would do the trick. But I have updated solution li'l differently. Pls try now.

Comment: @SaiKrishna Can you pls try now!!

Comment: @NitishNarang for getDates(1,5) output is 
 ["1/11/2018", "31/11/2018"] but it should be  ["1/11/2018", "30/11/2018"]

Comment: I see @SaiKrishna There are various use cases to cover.. and that's why I have now included month as well in my solution so that we can check for any month..

Comment: @NitishNarang  Thanks for the answer. it works perfectly :D

Comment: You're Welcome @SaiKrishna. :)

Comment: @NitishNarang i am using JavaScript in Thingworx and above code doesn't work over there.
Is there any different approach for this one

Comment: it is just saying compilation error. I think '=>' is not compatible to the version used in thingworx

Comment: Probably. But you can easily convert this to ES5. `d =>` to `function(d) {}`

Comment: For console.log(getDates(10,1,2)) or console.log(getDates(9,1,2)) i am not getting correct ones

Answer (score 0):

```
function getRange(week1, week2){
    var start = (moment().startOf('month') >  moment().startOf('month').add(week1 - 1, 'week').startOf('week')) ? moment().startOf('month') : moment().startOf('month').add(week1 - 1, 'week').startOf('week');
    var end   = ( moment().endOf('month')  <  moment().startOf('month').add(week2 - 1 , 'week').endOf('week')) ? moment().endOf('month'): moment().startOf('month').add(week2 - 1 , 'week').endOf('week');

    console.log(start.format('D/MM/YYYY'))
    console.log(end.format('D/MM/YYYY'))

}
```

If you can use moment.js

Comment: For getRange(1,5)  the output is
28/10/2018
01/12/2018
but output should be as 

1/11/2018
30/11/2018
My requirement is it should be in current month should not jump to other month

Comment: You could add conditionals to check if the start and end of the week are outside the current month

Comment: @SaiKrishna—you should put your requirements in the question, not in comments for an answer.